# Handle redirection in async calls

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app where on initial load the user is redirected to sign in page. Once the user is authenticated, he is then taken to homepage. While verifying the user, an `HttpOnly` cookie is also set to the browser. So now to remove the hassle for user to login every time he refreshes the app or opens it in another tab. I'm sending a authenticate request back to the server inside [beforeModel](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) hook of my application route. This will verify the user and page loads as expected. However if the server response has 401 (either because user logged out or cookie expired) the app will redirect him to login page. Everything works fine and as expected.

But there are few things tricky to resolve.

1. If the user gives path as /login I need to wait for the authenticate request to complete before deciding on to render the login template or to redirect to home screen if he is already logged in.
2. Also wait for validate call to complete before executing the [model](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) hook in target url. I saw the modal request going to server even when the response was 401 for authenticate call.

A good example is in **github** page, where once you log in and go to /login page they take you to your home page.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiment with routes.
I came up with this solution.

1. On every url request( either by refresh or entered path ), store the url unless it is for `/login`. This would be done in most likely `beforeModel` hook of application route.
2. Then on each topmost route of route hierarchy that an authenticated user can browse through have it redirect to login route.
3. On login route make the appropriate call to the API for authentication. If user is logged in transition to the stored url or to homepage if nothing is stored. If however 401 comes back load the template for the same.
   Make sure that your async call for the API is made in one of `beforeModel`, `model` or `afterModel` hook, and you have the call to API in a return statment, otherwise the template will load no matter.

NOTE:
1. You can have the url stored in some `service` which will be accessible throughout app. You can also have the service store other login information for future use.
2. In point (2), make sure to do some check before redirecting to `/login` in case of unnecessary redirection. Suppose if  the route was transitioned internally rather than through page load. 3. Don't forget to handle 401 case in your authenticate request, or it may just display nothing on page with an error in console.

Hope this helps